# how to send api response array in code codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating api in codeigniter in which i am checking both email and mobilenumber field for updating & in that check it for both field. my single message is go to response but in both casess how can i send both email and mobile number is exists

```
    if((isset($postData['email'])) && $postData['email']!="")
        {
        
                 $message["email_unique"]='Email already exists';
                 return $this->response(array("status" => "400", "message" =>$message), 400);
             
            
        }
        if((isset($postData['mobileNumber'])) && $postData['mobileNumber']!="")
        {
             $mobilenumber=$postData['mobileNumber'];
            
                 $message["mobilenumber_unique"]='Mobile Number already exists';
                 return $this->response(array("status" => "400", "message" =>$message), 400);
            
             
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Check this code*

"400", 
          "message" =>$message
        ]);
        exit;
      } else {
        $message['success'] = "Successful";  // success messsage if needed 
        $data = null;  // whatever data you need to pass in success resposne - either fetch from Database or hardcoded
        // validated flow
        echo json_encode([
          "status" => "200", 
          "message" =>$message,
          "data" => $data
        ]);
      }
    
    ?>

==================================

```
Success resposne:
{"status":"200","message":{"success":"Successful"},"data":null}

 Failed response:
 {"status":"400","message":{"error_email":"Email address required.","error_mobile":"Mobile number required."}}

If email exists and mobile number empty then 
Failed response:
{"status":"400","message":{"error_mobile":"Mobile number required."}}
```